# Swf file won't play anymore in Iceweasel / chromium

Tags: debian, chrome, iceweasel, swf

I'm running on Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux Sid

Since roughly the beginning of the year I can't seem to play a swf file from my navigators.

Chrome instead of playing it will save it automatically. Iceweasel did the same at first, but now It will open new tabs endlessly when trying to open it.

The flash files I try to open are downloaded from this page : http://www.online-stopwatch.com/download-stopwatch/

The flash file tested :

This one : http://www.online-stopwatch.com/download-stopwatch/download.php?f=interval-timer-offline

The files are located under my personal download directory.

I've also tried to put them on my personal web server with the same results.

I don't know where/how to report this bug if this is really one.

In the mean time I'd take any alternative way, tried gnash without success.

Thanks for your help !

edit : corrected links

Comment: I see the same behaviour on my system which plays flash just fine, except the 1st link says 'Page not found'. Do other flash-based sites (e.g. youtube) work?

Comment: Thanks, corrected the links ( copypaste dumbness )
Yes youtube and others works..
Any idea where to report that, if need to ?